# Django LDAP authentication

Tags: django, ldap, django-login

Given an username and password, I want to authenticate against a LDAP directoy with these credentials in one of my Django apps. I've been taking a look [Django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/index.html) but I still don't know how to use it properly once I've configured it.

On the one hand, I receive a JSON with username and password and I need to add an user to LDAP with these credentials. And, on the other hand, in subsequent request, I need to check that the user who makes the request belongs to LDAP (and **only LDAP not the own Django backend**, so if there's an user with the same credentials in the Django users database should't be allow to continue).

I've tried something like this to add an user:

**authbackends.py**

```
class CustomLDAPBackend(LDAPBackend):

    def authenticate(self, username, password, **kwargs):
        # Add user to LDAP
        user = LDAPBackend.authenticate(self, username, password)
        return user
```

So I can import it in my view to add the user to LDAP.

Could anyone outline a solution?

Comment: Checkout https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/

Comment: After reading your question, I think these links could help you. For the authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689712/django-python-ldap-authentication/41692949#41692949 and for the checking/creating user:  https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/reference.html#django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend.get_or_create_user . Let me know about it.

Comment: @GileadKenzo Thanks! I've found this link which can be useless as well: http://fle.github.io/combine-ldap-and-classical-authentication-in-django.html The point is, since I only want to  authenticate users with LDAP in just one of my apps. How to explicitly use my CustomLDAPBackend in the view of that app?

Comment: @Alex_Loar. You almost got it. Set Django settings with your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS values... Thank you :) :)

Comment: @GileadKenzo Thanks for your answer. Yes, that's how I got it but I only want to authenticate the users of that specific app of my project with LDAP not the Django backend. Given the case where I have an user (username=example/pass=my_pass) in my Django backend authentication but not my LDAP Backend this user will be able to authenticate because of Django tries to authenticate in all of the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. This is why I want to use explicitly the LDAP Backend for this app.

Comment: @Alex_Loar. I did it, but I need to refresh it... Let me check it. But, did you try to comment the other authentication methods?

Comment: @GileadKenzo I already have a custom backend authentication for my own User (which I want to keep) and now I'm trying to authenticate with LDAP the users from one of my endpoints of my project. I appreciate your help :) I'll post whatever solution I find.

Comment: Thanks :). I keep an eye on it...